# Apply texture tile tint to SVG

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I'm trying to apply a texture tint to the SVG.
It's working almost fine but I need to make the texture as a tile for a better image quality

```
<filter id="composite" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
    <feImage result="sourceTwo" xlink:href="_link_" />
    <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="sourceTwo" operator="arithmetic" k1="1"/>
</filter>
```

How to replace feImage with a tile of the same image

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unloco/m0pqq1ja/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the feTile primitive is for - but there is a regression bug in Chrome that clips the content - this is reported and a fix has been checked in (but still - buggy for now).

```html
<svg width="500px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 500 600">
    <defs>
  <filter id="composite" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
      <feImage result="sourceTwo" xlink:href="http://demo.prestalife.net/media/wood.jpg" width="34" height="34"/>
            <feTile result="tiledImage"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="tiledImage" operator="arithmetic" k1="1" k2="0" k3="0" k4="0"/>
  </filter>
    </defs>
    
    <text x="0" y="20">Original image</text>
    <image width="34" height="34" x="0" y="30" xlink:href="http://demo.prestalife.net/media/wood.jpg" />
    
    <g filter="url(#composite)">
        <rect fill="red" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="80" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll just use large tiles for now, please send me the bug report link to follow it